# Multipe passes at once in Passbook thru link

Tags: passbook

I'm searching everywhere on Google and find a few hints that it's possible.. But is it?

So i have one QR-Code, scan this with the Passbook app and than it adds multipe passes (event tickets). Or do they need to be scanned in all seperate?

If possible, do you maybe have a example JSON code?

Comment: Where have you seen the hints? The QR scanner expects a single PKPASS file to be returned by the URL contained within the QR code, so I don't see how more than one pass could be returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Passbook App scanner will only allow you to add a pass if ALL of the following are true:

- The QR code contains a URL
- The URL scheme is `https` and the server certificate is valid and can be authenticated (I.e not self signed)
- The URL returns a `Content-Type` header of `application/vnd.apple.pkpass`
- The URL body contains a single `.pkpass` bundle

Adding multiple passes via the Passbook App scanner from a single QR code is currently not possible.  The only way to add multiple passes is via your own app using the `addPasses:withCompletionHandler:` method of the [PKPassLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PKPassLibrary_Ref/PKPassLibrary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012157-CLSCHPKPassLibrary-SW17) class.